# Unable to add custom links to OHAttributeLabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, hyperlink, uilabel

I am using OHAttributeLabel to add custom links to my label's text. The code that I am using is pasted below. It used to work with the older version of OHAttributed label (2010), however with the new version (recently updated), the text in my label are no longer clickable as links.

Can anyone advise what I am missing here?

```
// Set Question Label
Question *question = self._answerForCell.question;
NSString *questionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q: %@", question.text];
CustomOHAttributLabel *thisQuestionLabel = (CustomOHAttributLabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:QUESTIONLABEL_TAG];

//Set up dictionary for question
NSString *questionStr = [question.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *urlForQn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dailythingsfm://redirect_to/questions/%@/answers?text=%@&nickname=%@&question_id=%@&question_curious=%i&showEveryOneTab=%i", question.slug, questionStr, [[UserInfo sharedUserInfo] getNickname], question.qid, question.curious, 1];
NSString *qnStartIndex = @"0";
NSString *qnLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [questionText length]];

NSDictionary *qnDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:qnStartIndex, @"start", qnLength, @"length", urlForQn, @"url", nil];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:qnDict];
[thisQuestionLabel setLabelwithText:questionText fontSize:QUESTION_FONT_SIZE andSubStringToURLArrayViaRange:array withHexColor:@"#555555"];


//Method to set the text in UILabel to a custom link
- (void)setLabelwithText:(NSString *)text fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize andSubStringToURLArrayViaRange:(NSArray *)array withHexColor:(NSString *)textColor
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:text];
    [attrStr setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
    [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self removeAllCustomLinks];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        NSString *start = [dict objectForKey:@"start"];
        NSString *length = [dict objectForKey:@"length"];
        NSString *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];

        NSUInteger startIndex = [start intValue];
        NSUInteger len = [length intValue];

        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startIndex, len);

        [attrStr setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize] range:range];
        [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:textColor] range:range];
        [self addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:url] inRange:range];
    }

    self.attributedText = attrStr;
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing the delegate method for handling the link action?

Comment: Yah I am. Actually I just realized the issue. It seems that the addCustomLink method does not work, I needed to use a different method that comes with the latest library version called 'setLink'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use 'setLink' method instead of addCustomLink for the latest OHAttribute Library (3.2.1)